# How to remove common suffix from all files in windows 10?

Tags: windows, powershell, file, command, rename

I have a bunch of files (hundreds) that end with a "GS.ipt". The number of characters before the GS are different in every file. I would like to just remove the GS and have all my files become whatever is before the GS and maintain the .ipt extension. How can I do this? CMD prompt or powershell? Ideally CMD I am not familiar with powershell.

rename "*GS.ipt" "*//.ipt"
I tried this, but I got the following error:
The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.

Comment: Please [format your post properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Answer (score 0):

A PowerShell solution that combines [`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem) with [`Rename-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/rename-item) and a [delay-bind script block](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_script_blocks#using-delay-bind-script-blocks-with-parameters) that uses the [regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions)-based [`-replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#replacement-operator) operator to remove the `GS` suffix from the file's base name.

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter *GS.ipt |
  Rename-Item -NewName { ($_.BaseName -replace 'GS$') + $_.Extension }
```